# How does float:left; and display:inline; property adjust with display:block;?

Tags: html, css

ok hi guys i am really confused here now.I have my **CSS and HTML** code below.

**CSS-:**

```
 #nav_wrapper ul li{

         //float: left;
         padding-left: 70px;
         position: relative;
         left: 33px;
         display: inline;


     }
     #nav_wrapper ul li a{

         text-decoration: none;
         //display: block;
         border: 1px solid black;

     }
```

**Below is my HTML CODE-:**

```
<div id="nav_wrapper">
                   <ul>
                       <li><a href="#">ELECTRONICS</a> </li> 
                       <li><a href="#">APPLIANCES</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">MEN</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">WOMEN</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">BABY&KIDS</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">HOME&FURNITURE</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">BOOKS&MORE</a></li>

                   </ul>

           </div>
```

Now my issue is when i use `display: inline;` in `#nav_wrapper ul li` all the **li** elements align them self **horizontally**.And then when i write `display: block;`(commented for now) in `#nav_wrapper ul li a`(commented for now)  they align them self **vertically**.Now if i comment `display: inline;` and remove comments from `//float: left;`.They align them self horizontally again.How is it working ?????

**MY POINT IS-:**

How does  **display: inline;**  and **float: left;** property are adjusting them self with `//display: block;` or i am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Basically There is two type of element in HTML.

1. Block type
2. Inline

Anchor tag(a) is a inline element. So when you use 'display: block;' in Anchor tag(a), it behave like block type element and like other Block type element it takes full width and it looks like vertically aligned.  So use the following code and hope it will be helpful -

#nav_wrapper ul li{

```
     display: inline;

 }
```

#nav_wrapper ul li a{

```
     text-decoration: none;
     border: 1px solid black;
     padding: based on your design;
     margin: based on your design;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally list(li) are shown vertically. But when we have to arrange the list(li) horizontally we can give the display property as inline or can give float:left. Normally block elements like div are shown vertically. If we want to arrange them in horizontal, we can give style as display: inline or give float as left. Please go through the link which i have posted previously to understand about the display properties.

Answer (score -1):

## nav_wrapper ul li{

```
     float: left;
     padding-left: 70px;
     position: relative;
     left: 33px;
     display: inline-block;


 }
 #nav_wrapper ul li a{

     text-decoration: none;
     border: 1px solid black;

 }
```

//try the above code